# Angularjs: Is there any way to remove the selected item from the drop-down of bootstrap ui typeahead?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Angular UI Bootstrap typeahead. I have a situation where I need to make multiple selections from the drop-down. The item already selected need to remove from the drop-down so that anyone can't select the same item again.

I find a way to select the label with build in call back function but can't remove the item from the list.
Any workaround on this?

**[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/mhYzPjrhku2YOAPJTHVj?p=preview)**

```
  $scope.itemSelected = function($label ){
   $scope.item = $label;
   console.log($scope.item);
}
```

Comment: From Plunker its not multiselector. please fix it 1st. Thanks

Comment: AFAIK bootstrap ui typeaheaddoesn't allow to make multiple selections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways, I would clone `statesWithFlags`

```
$scope.currentStatesWithFlags = angular.copy($scope.statesWithFlags);
```

and run filter on copied list as:

```
$scope.itemSelected = function( item,  model,  label,  event){

    $scope.currentStatesWithFlags = $scope.currentStatesWithFlags.filter(function(_item){
               return item.name !== _item.name;
     });
  }
```

In HTML:

```
 placeholder="Custom template" 
        uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in currentStatesWithFlags"
```

<kbd>**[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QEMpQzICiFRXURZ06blf?p=preview)**</kbd>